# Is it possible to eliminate the the ability to add media to a JSQMessagesViewController

Tags: uitoolbar, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am integrating this into my app and do not want me users to be able to add media to their message threads.  The input messages toolbar [documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/JSQMessagesViewController/7.3.4/Classes/JSQMessagesInputToolbar.html) does not have any reference to media or attachments.  Is it possible to remove this feature from the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will remove that nasty bugger I put it in the `viewDidLoad`

```
self.inputToolbar?.contentView?.leftBarButtonItem = nil
```

Comment: That did it. Obj-C `self.inputToolbar.contentView.leftBarButtonItem = nil;`